# QString and Embedded Nulls

Tags: qt

From https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html

"A QString can embed '\0' characters (QChar::Null). The size() function always returns the size of the whole string, including embedded '\0' characters."

Yet I am observing:

```
QString frameDataAsString =
    "SEND\n"
    "content-length:23\n\n"
    "Before a Null\0And after";
```

and in GDB:

```
(gdb) p frameDataAsString
$1 = "SEND\ncontent-length:23\n\nBefore a Null"
(gdb) p frameDataAsString.size()
$2 = 37
```

How then, does one "embed a NULL" into the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor `QString::QString(const char*)` cannot be used to embed `\0` characters. It will copy the the passed argument just until the first 0 terminator (regardless whether it was encoded explicitly or appended implicitly).

I considered to use a temporary `QByteArray` but the doc. ([QString::QString(const QByteArray &ba)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QString-8)
) mentions that the resp. constructor `QString::QString(const QByteArray&)` will consider 0 terminators as well.

Surprisingly, the `QString::from` functions (e.g. [QString::fromLatin1()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromLatin1), [QString::fromUtf8()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromUtf8)) seem to consider the passed length correctly.

The OP found yet another method – using the [QStringLiteral()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QStringLiteral). It can be applied exclusively to C string literals.

Demo:

```
// Qt header:
#include <QtCore>

// main application
int main()
{
  const char cstr[] = "A string with a \0 inside.";
  const size_t sizeCStr = sizeof cstr / sizeof *cstr, lenCStr = sizeCStr - 1;
  const QByteArray qBytes(cstr, sizeCStr);
  qDebug() << "qBytes:" << qBytes << "length:" << qBytes.size();
  const QString qStr0(qBytes);
  qDebug() << "qStr0:" << qStr0 << "length:" << qStr0.size();
  const QString qStr1 = QString::fromLatin1(cstr, sizeCStr);
  qDebug() << "qStr1:" << qStr1 << "length:" << qStr1.size();
  const QString qStr2 = QString::fromUtf8(cstr, sizeCStr);
  qDebug() << "qStr2:" << qStr2 << "length:" << qStr2.size();
  const QString qStrL(QStringLiteral("A string with a \0 inside."));
  qDebug() << "qStrL:" << qStrL << "length:" << qStrL.size();
}
```

Output:

```
qBytes: "A string with a \x00 inside.\x00" length: 26
qStr0: "A string with a " length: 16
qStr1: "A string with a \u0000 inside.\u0000" length: 26
qStr2: "A string with a \u0000 inside.\u0000" length: 26
qStrL: "A string with a \u0000 inside." length: 25
```

Comment: "Surprisingly, the QString::from functions (e.g. QString::fromLatin1(), QString::fromUtf8()) seem to consider the passed length correctly:" - that's because one passes the length explicitly, the only way for the function to find out where the string ends if it can't rely on null termination.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I would have expected the same for `QByteArray`. Hence, I had lowered my expectations. ;-)

Comment: Ah :). It's documented but seems inconsistent to me, too: "The given byte array is converted to Unicode using fromUtf8(). Stops copying at the first 0 character, otherwise copies the entire byte array."

Comment: We might mention in the answer for future searchers, that QStringLiteral works as well. It is unfortunate that we cannot come from a QByteArray, as it would be nice if I could use the same parsing code when y source data is a string or binary, and deal with human readable text.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz Done.

Answer (score 0):

You're constructing the `QString` from a `const char *` literal.  The 'embedded' null character will be treated as the terminating null hence the truncation you see under the debugger.

If you want to embed a null you could use something like (untested)...

```
QString frameDataAsString =
    QString("SEND\n"
            "content-length:23\n\n"
            "Before a Null%1And after").arg('\0');
```